# Convertir salida XML a columnas

Tags: awk, sed

Tengo la siguiente estructura en formato XML que se repite varias veces (pongo una parte):

```
<planned>true</planned>
<input index="2">
  <value>2</value>
</input>
<input index="3">
  <value>3</value>
</input>
```

Me gustaría poder imprimir en formato en columnas quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
true 2 3
```

Es posible mediante awk/sed?

Gracias!

Comment: parsear un XML con awk o sed es muy frágil, mejor usar herramientas del tipo xmllint. A todo esto, sería conveniente que mostraras qué has intentado

Comment: voy a informarte y os comento. gracias!

Comment: Ese XML tal cual está puesto no es válido. Entiendo que aunque hayas puesto solo una parte, esos elementos cuelgan de alguna 'raiz', es así?

Answer (score 0):

La herramienta [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) es útil para tratar archivos con contenido etiquetado.

Para este caso particular, `pandoc` puede eliminar el etiquetado si se le pide interpretar el formato de entrada como HTML (opción `-f html`). Se usa posteriormente `sed` o `awk` para dar formato al texto plano generado.

```bash
pandoc -f html -t plain ARCHIVO.xml | sed 's/\(true\|false\) [[:digit:]]\+ [[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]*/&\n/g'
```

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que `ARCHIVO.xml` contiene

```html
<planned>true</planned>
<input index="2">
  <value>2</value>
</input>
<input index="3">
  <value>3</value>
</input>

<planned>false</planned>
<input index="4">
  <value>40</value>
</input>
<input index="5">
  <value>50</value>
</input>
```

obtenemos:

```bash
true 2 3 
false 40 50
```